# "Undefined index" when uploading image using php

Tags: php, image-upload

I have this form:

```
<form action="image_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Image 1: <input type="file" name="event_image" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and this php code (image_upload.php):

```
print_r($_FILES);
if ((($_FILES["event_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["event_image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["event_image"]["size"] < 200000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["event_image"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["event_image"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    if (file_exists("/images/events/" . $_FILES["event_image"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["event_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["event_image"]["tmp_name"],
      "/images/events/" . $_FILES["event_image"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["event_image"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

I have no idea where this is going wrong as I've had the same code working before.

I am getting the following error though...

Array ( [event_image] => Array ( [name] => my_image.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpvIYmAZ [error] => 0 [size] => 48512 ) )

Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../../images/events/my_image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /path/event_upload.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpvIYmAZ' to '../../../images/events/my_image.jpg' in /path/event_upload.php on line 25 Stored in: upload/my_image.jpg

Notice: Undefined index: event_image in /path/event_upload.php on line 57

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` at the top of it, please. Also, on the `if` you should add the condition `isset($_FILES['event_image'])` as the first condition to be evaluated. You should not evaluate anything else if that is false, or you'll get the undefined index errors.

Comment: The image doesn't exist in `$_FILES` possibly because it failed to upload in the first place. Check if `$_POST['event_image']` is set and verify you didn't exceed `max_upload_size` or `post_max_size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... it would appear it was a folder permissions issue on my local machine... Just had to chmod the folder.

Thanks for all the advice though.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly did you do with folder/file permissions to remove the error ?

Comment: In my case, I used Dreamweaver. I right clicked the directory in the files window and selected "Set permissions" where I was able to change the permissions to exactly what I needed to.

Answer (score 1):

The `$_FILES` array is numerically indexed under each property key, to deal with multiple uploads.

You have to hardcode index zero, using `$_FILES["event_image"]["type"][0]`, `$_FILES["event_image"]["name"][0]` etc. You have to change every line where you are using `$_FILES`without the numeric indexes.

**NOTICE**: Original answer edited to fix the proper location of the numeric indexes within the array.

Comment: That's not true. $_FILES is an associated array with the name field mapped as key: http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: You're right, I messed up! The numeric indexes for multiple uploads is deep inside that array. Answer edited considering the proper $_FILES structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know how the $_FILES object look like, right before line number 8, insert this `echo "<PRE>" . print_r ($_FILES, true) . "</PRE>";`